# Java Proxy using SOCKS instead of Http

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to a server through proxy. Below is the code I am using to set the proxy.

```
    try {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
        System.out.println("detecting proxies");
        List l = null;
        try {
            l = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("https://www.google.com"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to list the proxy..." + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (l != null) {
            for (Iterator iter = l.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                java.net.Proxy proxy = (java.net.Proxy) iter.next();
                System.out.println("proxy type: " + proxy.type());
                InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
                if (addr == null) {
                    System.out.println("No Proxy");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("proxy hostname: " + addr.getHostName());
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
                    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", addr.getHostName());
                    System.out.println("proxy port: " + addr.getPort());
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));
                    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(addr.getPort()));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I am using the below code to send the server requests.

```
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonValue);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(settings.getServiceUrl() + "/" + service).addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic(settings.getServiceUserName(), settings.getServicePassword())).post(body).build();
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder =new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    OkHttpClient client = builder.readTimeout(6000 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(6000 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();
```

And I am getting the below error message.

```
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.java:235)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:177)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
```

Any idea on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Maybe you can found some help [arround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174375/java-httpurlconnection-uses-socks-proxy-instead-of-http)

Comment: This problem seems to be quite related to this StackOverflow question, it maybe can help here to solve this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215053/why-does-my-socks-proxy-code-throw-socketexception-malformed-reply-from-socks-s